# Tweepy Streaming

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a problem. I am trying to stream real-time Tweets from defined users with some keywords, but my program just doesn't print out any Tweet. What should I do?

CODE:

```
import tweepy

stream = tweepy.Stream(
  "TeFq5YKqyyWhJ4rbzttiCwQEB", "dbYVgL1BhZfmsYeYkOpKmIG3TO6dTIWJWU1LHkGZVFad8Xw7EJ",
  "1421056459912142849-kfLnbgSOmyEXczmYOhy0TfDDX1LmyI", "3pZpDBQKDxioiiHy40nWGjfsQNcL2VbsAbFdfLwJhiupB"
)

stream.filter(follow=['1421056459912142849'], track=['questionable', 'doubtful', 'ruled out'])

class printer(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

printer1 = printer(
  "TeFq5YKqyyWhJ4rbzttiCwQEB", "dbYVgL1BhZfmsYeYkOpKmIG3TO6dTIWJWU1LHkGZVFad8Xw7EJ",
  "1421056459912142849-kfLnbgSOmyEXczmYOhy0TfDDX1LmyI", "3pZpDBQKDxioiiHy40nWGjfsQNcL2VbsAbFdfLwJhiupB"
)

printer1.sample(languages="en")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll want to revoke and regenerate your credentials now.

`Stream.filter` is a blocking call, so the first non-subclassed `Stream` instance you're using, `stream`, is running and your program isn't reaching anything afterwards (i.e. the `Stream` subclass or it's instantiation and usage). By default, `Stream` only logs statuses received at the DEBUG level.